# variable does not increment

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, integer

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMainMenu.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEnterPatient_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnterPatient.Click


        ReDim Preserve Names(0 To i)
        Names(i) = txtPatientName.Text

        ReDim Preserve Heights(0 To i)
        Heights(i) = txtPatientHeight.Text

        ReDim Preserve Weights(0 To i)
        Weights(i) = txtPatientWeight.Text

        i = i + 1

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my code for when I click a button to enter data into three arrays but when I click the button the i does not increment. Also if I don't enter anything into the Height or Weight textbox and press the button I get the error: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

What is the problem here?
Thanks

Comment: How do you know it doesn't increment?  An empty string isn't a valid integer - what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Will `Dim i as Integer = 0` not reset your i each time you click the button thus making it 0 each time you try to redim your array?

Comment: sorry, stupid mistake. the label i was using to check the value of i did not have any code to make it the same value as i. Problem solved.

Comment: If you can, look at using List instead of an array. It'll save you a lot of trouble.